# How to split a dataframe by week on a particular starting weekday (e.g, Thursday)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I'm using Python, and I have a Dataframe in which all dates and weekdays are mentioned.
And I want to divide them into Week (Like - Thursday to Thursday)

Dataframe -
[image]

And Now I want to divide this dataframe in this format-

```
Date    Weekday
0   2021-01-07   Thursday
1   2021-01-08     Friday
2   2021-01-09   Saturday
3   2021-01-10     Sunday
4   2021-01-11     Monday
5   2021-01-12    Tuesday
6   2021-01-13  Wednesday
7   2021-01-14   Thursday,

Date    Weekday
0   2021-01-14   Thursday
1   2021-01-15     Friday
2   2021-01-16   Saturday
3  2021-01-17     Sunday
4  2021-01-18     Monday
5  2021-01-19    Tuesday
6  2021-01-20  Wednesday
7  2021-01-21   Thursday,

Date    Weekday
0  2021-01-21   Thursday
1  2021-01-22     Friday
2  2021-01-23   Saturday
3  2021-01-24     Sunday
4  2021-01-25     Monday
5  2021-01-26    Tuesday
6  2021-01-27  Wednesday
7  2021-01-28   Thursday,
Date    Weekday
0  2021-01-28   Thursday
1  2021-01-29     Friday
2  2021-01-30   Saturday.
```

In this Format but i don't know how can i divide this dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime` if the Date is not yet datetime type, then use the `dt.week` accessor to `groupby`:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.week)]
```

Alternatively, if you have several years, use `dt.to_period`:

```
dfs = [g for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W'))]
```

output:

```
[         Date   Weekday
 0  2021-01-07  Thursday
 1  2021-01-08    Friday
 2  2021-01-09  Saturday
 3  2021-01-10    Sunday,
           Date    Weekday
 4   2021-01-11     Monday
 5   2021-01-12    Tuesday
 6   2021-01-13  Wednesday
 7   2021-01-14   Thursday
 8   2021-01-14   Thursday
 9   2021-01-15     Friday
 10  2021-01-16   Saturday
 11  2021-01-17     Sunday,
           Date    Weekday
 12  2021-01-18     Monday
 13  2021-01-19    Tuesday
 14  2021-01-20  Wednesday
 15  2021-01-21   Thursday
 16  2021-01-21   Thursday
 17  2021-01-22     Friday
 18  2021-01-23   Saturday
 19  2021-01-24     Sunday,
           Date    Weekday
 20  2021-01-25     Monday
 21  2021-01-26    Tuesday
 22  2021-01-27  Wednesday
 23  2021-01-28   Thursday
 24  2021-01-28   Thursday
 25  2021-01-29     Friday
 26  2021-01-30   Saturday]
```

###### variants

As dictionary:

```
{k:g for k,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W'))}
```

reset_index of subgroups:

```
[g.reset_index() for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W'))]
```

weeks ending on Wednesday/starting on Thursday with [anchor offsets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets):

```
[g.reset_index() for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W-WED'))]
```

Comment: dfs = [g for i, g in dates_df.groupby(dates_df['Weekday'].eq('Thursday').cumsum())]  i tried this , but it is dividing data in this format  Date    Weekday
0   2021-01-07   Thursday
1   2021-01-08     Friday
2   2021-01-09   Saturday
3   2021-01-10     Sunday
4   2021-01-11     Monday
5   2021-01-12    Tuesday
6   2021-01-13  Wednesday, Date    Weekday
0   2021-01-14   Thursday
1   2021-01-15     Friday
2   2021-01-16   Saturday
3  2021-01-17     Sunday
4  2021-01-18     Monday
5  2021-01-19    Tuesday
6  2021-01-20  Wednesday, but i want Thursday to Thursday.

Comment: @KrishnaGupta this works only if you have all Thursdays and the dates are sorted, but yes, this is one alternative ;)

Comment: @Krishna use a custom week period: `[g.reset_index() for _,g in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('W-WED'))]`, see update